# Out of range float values are not JSON compliant: nan, Django Rest Framework with Json Serialization Exception

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I work with `rest_framework` to implement a `django` API. The table Order from my database has nan fields, and Nan generates the error `Out of range float values are not JSON compliant: nan`.
How to ensure that serializing Nan to JSON works.

```
#serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Order
    
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Order
       fields = ('id', 'status', 'description')
```

The serialization here is a black box, i don't find where to fix this.

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Which field are the floats? Can you share your model code?

Comment: @Daniel i have 18 fields, i just optimized the code, but i believe that many fields face the same problem

Answer (score 0):

JSON don't suport NaN values

You can correct the model data with the following command replacing NaN with None

```
from django.db.models import Q
import math
import decimal

MyModel.objects.filter(Q(field_name=math.nan) | Q(field_name=decimal.Decimal("NaN"))).update(field_name=None)
```

Or adding a method that validates that the value is not NaN inside the serializer, for your example it would be

```
#serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Order
import math
    
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     order_description = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
     class Metha:
         model = Order
         fields = ('id', 'status', 'order_description')

     def get_order_description(self, obj):
         if obj.description is not None and not math.isnan(obj.description):
             return obj.description
         return None
```